# RecyclerView only shows the items when the screen is "refreshed"

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, viewmodel, observers

I'm doing an APP and I have to show the itens from contacts in a `RecyclerView`.
But, when I enter in the APP the items don't show. But, if I go to another `Fragment` then back the `RecyclerView` is working properly.
I'm using the `MVVM` (ViewModelProvider) architecture with `LiveData` to receive the data from the `DataBase`.
Someone can help me to know what is wrong?
Look's like the Adapter isn't refreshing when the database data is received by the observer.
Here's all the code.

ViewModelCode:

```
private var _contactsWithConversation: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LastMessageModel>> = MutableLiveData()
    val contactsWithConversation: LiveData<ArrayList<LastMessageModel>> get() = _contactsWithConversation

fun getContactsWithConversationStarted(currentUserId: String, context: Context) {
        val contactsAtDatabase: ArrayList<UserProfileModel> = ArrayList()
        val contactsWithConversationStarted: ArrayList<LastMessageModel> = ArrayList()

        realtimeDatabase
            .child(context.getString(R.string.users))
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { usersIdTask ->
                if (usersIdTask.isSuccessful) {
                    for (user in usersIdTask.result.children) {
                        val currentUser = user.getValue(UserProfileModel::class.java)
                        contactsAtDatabase.add(currentUser!!)
                    }
                    for (contact in contactsAtDatabase) {
                        if (contact.userId != currentUserId) {
                            val senderRoom = contact.userId + currentUserId
                            realtimeDatabase
                                .child(context.getString(R.string.messages_database))
                                .child(senderRoom)
                                .child(context.getString(R.string.messages_database))
                                .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                        val lastChildren = snapshot.children.last()
                                            .getValue(MessageModel::class.java)
                                        if (contact.userId == lastChildren!!.receiverId) {
                                            val currentLastMessageModel = LastMessageModel(
                                                contact.name,
                                                contact.userId,
                                                contact.profilePictureLink,
                                                lastChildren.message ?: "",
                                                lastChildren.time ?: ""
                                            )
                                            contactsWithConversationStarted.add(
                                                currentLastMessageModel
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }

                                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                                    }
                                })
                        }
                    }
                    _contactsWithConversation.value = contactsWithConversationStarted
                }
            }
    }
```

MessagesFragment Code:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentMessagesBinding.inflate(inflater)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MessagesViewModel::class.java)
        lastMessageAdapterHandler()
        viewModel.getContactsWithConversationStarted(firebaseAuthentication.currentUser?.uid.toString(), requireContext())
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        observers()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun lastMessageAdapterHandler(){
        messageAdapter = MessageAdapter(lastMessageList, firebaseAuthentication.currentUser?.uid.toString(), requireContext(), object : MessageAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
            override fun onItemClickListener(messageData: LastMessageModel, position: Int) {
                val contactData = UserProfileModel(messageData.userId, "", messageData.name, "", "", messageData.profilePictureLink)
                findNavController().navigate(MessagesFragmentDirections.actionNavMessagesToChatFragment(contactData))
            }
        })
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = messageAdapter
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
    }

    private fun observers(){
        viewModel.contactsWithConversation.observe(requireActivity()){contactsWithConversation ->
            lastMessageList = contactsWithConversation
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

Adapter Code:

```
class MessageAdapter(var lastMessageList: ArrayList<LastMessageModel>, var currentUserId: String, var context: Context, var onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = MessageItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val messageData = lastMessageList[position]
        holder.messageItem.contactName.text = messageData.name
        holder.messageItem.contactLastMessage.text = messageData.lastMessage
        holder.messageItem.lastMessageTime.text = messageData.lastMessageTime
        if(messageData.userId != currentUserId){
            holder.messageItem.messageIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sended))
        }else{
            holder.messageItem.messageIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_received))
        }
        Picasso.get().load(messageData.profilePictureLink).into(holder.messageItem.contactPhoto)
        holder.messageItem.messageField.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(messageData, position)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = lastMessageList.size

    class MyViewHolder(val messageItem: MessageItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(messageItem.root)

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClickListener(messageData: LastMessageModel, position: Int)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your observer doesn't update the data in the adapter, so it won't see any changes:

```
viewModel.contactsWithConversation.observe(requireActivity()){ contactsWithConversation ->
    // replace some variable in the fragment with this new list
    lastMessageList = contactsWithConversation
    // tell the adapter its data has changed, when it hasn't
    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

The only way this would work is if the initial list you provided to the adapter was being modified - but that's not what happens, your update from the database creates a new list with the new data (which is the best way to do it anyway, avoids bugs and other issues):

```
fun getContactsWithConversationStarted(currentUserId: String, context: Context) {
    ...
    // create a new list to fill with data
    val contactsWithConversationStarted: ArrayList<LastMessageModel> = ArrayList()
    ...
    // set this new list on the LiveData
    _contactsWithConversation.value = contactsWithConversationStarted
```

So the adapter is unable to see this list, and the list it's using as its data set hasn't changed - so calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` won't show any changes!

The solution is to pass the new data to the adapter, preferably through a function. That way it can store the new data and update itself however it likes, anything from the simplest `notifyDataSetChanged()` to using a `DiffUtil`. The fragment doesn't need to know these details - it just passes the new data and lets the adapter handle it.

```
// in the adapter

fun setData(data: ArrayList<LastMessageModel) {
    lastMessageList = data
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}


// in the fragment's observer

messageAdapter.setData(contactsWithConversation)
```

Comment: Hello. Still not working. Just show the ```contactsWithConversation``` list when i refresh the fragment, like i go to another fragment then came back... i dont really know how can i make this works properly

Comment: @AntonyLajes what I posted is what you need to do to get the observer to display the current data in the `contactsWithConversation` `LiveData`. I don't know if your code is actually updating that `LiveData` correctly though. That `contactsWithConversationStarted.add` line in `onDataChange` is suspicious - adding to the list in the `LiveData` won't actually push an update to observers, if that's what you're trying to do, because the list reference itself (the `value` on the `LiveData`) isn't changing. You can force an update by setting `value` on the LiveData again with the same list

Comment: But setting a *new list* is better, because then you avoid potential bugs by modifying the current one (which is supposed to represent the old data) and then calling that new data. If something has a reference to that list object (which your adapter does) then its "current" data changes, and the "new" data is identical (because it's literally the same list object). That can lead to issues down the line, so it's better to just update with a new list object. This is also why it's better to use Kotlin's `List` in general, and `MutableList` only if you have a good reason to change the contents